# Aderet's Anonymous Sefer and Haskamah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books

In this post, https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/04/my-nom-de-plume-exposed/ , R' Michael Broyde says that "Finally, [Professor Marc B.] Shapiro informed me that the Aderet published a book anonymously, and included his own haskamah to the book (referring to himself in exalted language)." Does anyone have references to resources with more information about this incident?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Coffee Table and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Who is the aderet?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_David_Rabinowitz-Teomim

Answer (score 4):

The book in question is called Aharit HaShanim, and was indeed published anonymously by Aderet, with his own approbation. It discusses the topic of *vidui ma'aser*.

See footnote 1a to [this blogpost](http://ishimshitos.blogspot.com/2008/08/some-notes-on-marc-shapiros-studies-in.html) for photos of the title page and Aderet's approbation.

An updated version, without the approbations, can be found on HebrewBooks.org [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/21984).

---

For a further example, the title page of [Zekher L'Mikdash](http://hebrewbooks.org/32233) indicates anonymous authorship, but it is generally attributed (e.g. by HebrewBooks.org) to Aderet. It contains [an approbation](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32233&st=&pgnum=3) from Aderet himself.

See the comments section of [this blogpost](http://ishimshitos.blogspot.com/2008/08/some-notes-on-marc-shapiros-studies-in.html) for excerpts of an article by R. Ari Kahn discussing this case.

Comment: Thanks! Though it seems you snagged the second source from "b a" below after the fact.

Comment: @rami_bar_pappa I didn't see b a's post until after I finished editing mine. I found the second source from R. Kahn's comments on the blogpost I linked to.

Comment: Ah okay, understood, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

One such book is called Zecher Lemikdash (5649), on the laws of hakhel.

You can see his haskama on the first edition [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32233&st=&pgnum=3).

The [second posthumous publication](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22884&st=&pgnum=13) (5706) names him, with additions from his manuscript.

(Bibliographic information that helped me find the two editions came from [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hamaayan/Hamaayan_23.pdf).)